# How to Scrape Names of Results from a Website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I want to scrape the names of results from the following website: [RAJASTHAN TECHNICAL UNIVERSITY, KOTA](http://www.esuvidha.info/)

Below is my current code in Python:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

print(soup)
```

I get the following error when I try to print soup:

```
Couldn't access the inner elements of frame name="mainFrame" src="mainpage.php"/>
```

Comment: Your information is not clear what are you looking after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an iframe to deal with. You can instead use the iframe src as starting point and gather the required params for a POST request that matches what page does for results

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = {'Referer': 'http://www.esuvidha.info/rtURes/ResMainpage.php'}
    r = s.get('http://www.esuvidha.info/mainpage.php')
    soup= bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    data = {i['id']:i['value'] for i in soup.select('[type="hidden"][id]')}
    r = s.post('http://www.esuvidha.info/rtURes/ResMainpage.php', data=data)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    print(soup.select_one('fieldset > font').text)
```

[image]